# Is there a way to "block/hide" posts flagged with Spam/Dupe or very high downvotes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I know this is sorta a blunt question, but is there a way we can block or hide (remove from visibility) questions that are "un-useful" or "harmful" or otherwise flagged with flags such as: `Duplicate` `Spam` `Opinion-Based`

I find that there are many questions [closed] or [off-topic] or even just [too-broad] that are actually good questions with over 10 upvotes and working answers, But i would like to filter out the ones that are almost guaranteed useless. I only ask as I am digging through search A LOT, and its painful seeing the amount of flagged questions.

If this isn't possible (I don't think it is at the current time) then could this be a feature request? I feel it could be quite useful.

Also for those who are going to say "use the filter" Im looking for a way to physically remove the questions from showing up with ANY filter (Via a setting or autosaved filter) Of course this is only client side, and is only visual.

Comment: Sure, downvote, close vote, and delete vote. The only thing that _will_ keep these questions from being automatically deleted after the time threshold has been reached is answers.

Comment: Spam posts pretty much always get deleted near-immediately, and should not show up in search results at all. Upvoted duplicates very often do have useful information not contained in the canonical. As to your question, filtering out questions based on certain conditions is possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching, there are many operators you can use - all you really need is to figure out the exact filtering logic you want, feel free to autofill your searchbox with your desired filter.

Comment: We prefer to *delete* the ones that are completely useless, not just hide them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're searching, you can filter out certain questions with specific operators such as:

- `score:0..` : questions scoring at least 0
- `closed:no` : questions that aren't closed
- `duplicate:no` : questions that aren't closed as duplicates
- `locked:no` : questions that aren't locked
- `answers:1..`: questions with at least one answer

These can be mixed and matched and the numbers changed. Unfortunately, there is no way to filter further by close reason.

There is no way to remove questions that only have flags or close votes on them (as you need some rep to be able to see close votes and only mods can see flags). Spam, fortunately, is usually pretty quickly deleted, so the best thing you can do when you see something that [meets the criteria for spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/323179) is to flag it as spam: enough people flagging as spam deletes the post.

---

It's not exactly what you're looking for but it's something you can use right now.

Comment: Thanks, Also I wasn't really sure if such a thing was true in the first place, so ill have to stick with filter for now.